# segmentation fault using q sort?

Tags: c++, qsort

I am trying to sort a pointer array of characters using qsort and keep getting a segmentation fault when I compile. I will post the code for my qsort call and the compare function and any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
//count declaration
size_t count = (sizeof (strPtrsQsort)/sizeof (*strPtrsQsort));
//function call
qsort ((char *)ptr, size, sizeof(char), compare);

//compare function
int compare (const void *a, const void *b)
{
    const char **ia = (const char **)a;
    const char **ib = (const char **)b;
    return strcmp (*ia, *ib);
}
```

Comment: What is `count`, what is `strPtrsQsort` and are they present in the code snippet you posted? They are not used anywhere in `qsort`.

Comment: Why are you using C strings, raw arrays, and C's `qsort` in C++? Use `std::vector<std::string>` and `std::sort`.

Comment: If you are trying to sort an array of pointers, why the array element size is passed to `qsort` as `sizeof(char)`??? How is `ptr` declared? Why are you converting it to `char *` before passing to `qsort`?

Answer (score 0):

Judging by your `qsort` call, you are sorting an array of `char` elements: the base pointer type is passed to `qsort` as `char *` value and the element size is `sizeof(char)`. However, your comparison function is written for an array of *pointers* to `char`. That's completely incorrect and inconsistent. That is what is causing the crash.

In the accompanying text you state that you are "trying to sort a pointer array of characters". Why in that case are you specifying the element size as `sizeof(char)` and not as, say, `sizeof (char *)`?

Comment: Thanks for your help. I'm pretty new to pointers am just getting ahold of dereferencing. That helped a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Note that even when you're required to work with C-style raw arrays you can still use C++ STL algorithms, since pointers are in fact RandomAccessIterators. For example, this works:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

static
bool compare(const char *a, const char *b)
{
    return std::strcmp(a, b) < 0;
}

int main()
{
    const char *stringarray[] = {
        "zyxulsusd",
        "abcdef",
        "asdf"
    };

    std::sort(stringarray, stringarray + 3, compare);
    //                      -----------^
    // Just like a normal iterator the end iterator points
    // to an imaginary element behind the data.

    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        std::cout << stringarray[i] << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The primary advantage of this approach is type safety and it avoids thus most pitfalls common with C-style functions like `qsort`.

Comment: I'm not sure that `stringarray[3]` is valid, even though you just take the address of it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26289918/is-an-valid-where-n-is-the-size-of-the-array

Comment: changed to alternative syntax