# Is dereferencing a NULL pointer considered unspecified or undefined behaviour?

Tags: c++, pointers, null, undefined-behavior, unspecified-behavior

The consensus of stackoverflow questions say that it is undefined behaviour.

However, I recently saw a 2016 talk by Charles Bay titled:
*Instruction Reordering Everywhere:  The C++ 'As-If" Rule and the Role of Sequence.*

At [37:53](https://youtu.be/8yUSMJWlEsk?t=37m53s)  he shows the following:

> **C++ Terms**
>
> **Undefined** Behaviour: Lack of Constraints
> (order of globals initialization)
>
> **Unspecified** Behaviour: Constraint Violation
> (dereferencing NULL
> pointer)

Now I have conflicting information.
Was this a typo?  Has anything changed?

Comment: It is ass-backwards. Fail!

Comment: The examples should be swapped. It is most likely a typo!

Comment: As Nawaz says. The standard doesn't specify the total order in which globals / statics are initialised, but it does define that they _are_ initialised (in some _unspecified_ order). A null pointer dereference is still undefined behaviour.

Comment: @Xeo: Meanwhile, DR#315 (http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_closed.html#315) claims that dereferencing a null pointer is OK for calling a member function, if there's no lvalue-to-rvalue conversion involved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The examples are associated with the wrong things.   Regardless of what version of the C++ standard you assume (i.e. nothing has changed within the standards, in this regard).

Dereferencing a NULL pointer gives undefined behaviour.   The standard does not define any constraint on what happens as a result.

The order of globals initialisation is an example of unspecified behaviour   (the standard guarantees that all globals will be initialised [that's a constraint on how globals are initialised] but the order is not specified).

Answer (score 3):

It is undefined  behavior.

From **8.3.2 References** of the C++11 Standard (emphasis mine):

> 5 ... [ *Note*: in particular, a null reference cannot exist in a well-defined program, because the only way to create such a reference would be to bind it to the “object” obtained by **dereferencing a null pointer, which causes undefined behavior**. As described in 9.6, a reference cannot be bound directly to a bit-field. —*end note* ]

Comment: Not there... it is somewhere else the spec has mentioned that *dereferencing* nullptr is UB.

Comment: @Nawaz, I found the undefined behavior bit inside a *Note*.

Comment: Well, it means the first quote is irrelevant here (if so, it should be removed from this answer).

Comment: @Nawaz, true. I find it rather strange that such an important aspect of the language will be left to a *Note*.

Comment: @Nawaz, I'll be grateful if you can point me to other such sections of the standard.

Comment: I just asked a question about this matter http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39860732/the-apparent-underspecification-of-one-past-the-end-subscripting-for-both-raw-a and it looks woefully underspecified to me. DR#315 (http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_closed.html#315) claims that it is OK to derefence a null pointer (marked NAD). However, DR#232 (http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#232), which was planning to allow null pointer dereference has been in "drafting" stage since 2000. The corresponding wording in not in the standard.

Comment: @AnT, thanks for the links. It was educational for me to go through your question.