std::array<T, 0> and weird behavior
The following code generates a RET instruction in GCC (https://godbolt.org/z/Yz7fE4xK7)
void f( ) {
    std::array<int, 0> a;
    std::array<int, 1> b;
    std::copy_n(a.begin( ), 0, b.begin( ));
} 

However, the following code generates an UD2 instruction from GCC 13 onwards (https://godbolt.org/z/7f9KMvr76), apparently due to triggering undefined behavior.
void f( ) {
    std::array<int, 0> a;
    std::array<int, 1> b;
    std::copy_n(&a[0], 0, &b[0]);
} 

I believe this is a GCC bug, but I would like to ask your opinion before actually reporting it, since undefined behavior is a tricky topic.

fyi it's a gcc 12.4 to 13.1 change

Note that a[0] returns a reference to element 0 which does not exist as no internal array will have been created - not sure if this is UB or not .... checking.

what is the point of such an operation? that actually does nothing. the docs says: There is a special case for a zero-length array (N == 0). In that case, array.begin() == array.end(), which is some unique value. The effect of calling front() or back() on a zero-sized array is undefined. so probably UD2/RET is a right instruction for this code.

In general, if you have int a[n]; it is valid to construct the pointer &a[0] + n == &a[n] as long as such pointer is not dereferenced. Hence my question.

The question maybe is whether the expression a[0] is considered to dereference that pointer, even if the only thing you do with the resulting lvalue is apply & to it.

int a[0] in not allowed in C++ Array declaration "...which evaluates to a value greater than zero..." So there might be a specialization for std::array that does not use an internal c-array.

Following @nate-eldredge comment, I think this sums it up: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26289918/is-an-valid-where-n-is-the-size-of-the-array

@RodrigoCastro is a duplicate

note that containers all have a data function which gives you a pointer without having to do &a[0] which avoids the UB https://godbolt.org/z/T3z78cEbj

@AlanBirtles note that "...If size() is ​0​, data() may or may not return a null pointer...."  https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array/data

@RichardCritten yep, and passing a null pointer to std::copy_n with n equal to 0 is perfectly fine

@AlanBirtles thanks and works as expected - live - https://godbolt.org/z/Mf4KTK5GP

a[0] is undefined behavior for a zero-sized std::array.
a[n] is defined to be equivalent to *(a.begin() + n) for a sequence container.
A zero-size std::array is a bit of a special case that differs from the other cases. The only guarantee given for a zero-size std::array is that begin() and end() produce the same value.
Regardless, even if there was a proper zero-size range, a.begin() + 0 cannot be a dereferenceable iterator because it, at best, points one-after the last element of the range, i.e. it is the end iterator of the range.
Dereferencing an end iterator (*) is a precondition violation and causes undefined behavior.
In the first example there is no problem, because you never dereference a.begin().
Practically there is nothing different to &a[a.size()] in the general case. That is also undefined behavior, even if the iterators are just pointers, because a[a.size()] dereferences the end iterator (or one-after-the-last-element pointer). It is not specific to std::array either and would apply analogously to any random access container or built-in array.


In general, if you have int a[n]; it is valid to construct the pointer &a[0] + n == &a[n] as long as such pointer is not dereferenced.

That is not true in C++. &a[n] is define equivalent to &*(a + n) in both C and C++.
In C there is a special rule that effectively says that if & is directly applied after * to a pointer, then the expression doesn't actually dereference the pointer and instead behaves as if &* was dropped, i.e. &*(a + n) behaves like a + n.
In C++ this exception does not exist. &*(a + n) actually does dereference a + n and that has undefined behavior given that a + n is the one-past-the-array pointer which must not be dereferenced.
But even if that exception did exist in C++ as well, the code with std::array would still have undefined behavior because it violates the standard library preconditions, regardless of the core language rules for pointers. (The iterators don't have to be implemented as pointers at all for that matter.)
